# OrmLite Select with return Type not dynamic

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack

in a simple example like this one

```
var query = db.From<Employee>()
    .Join<Department>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select<Employee, Department>((employee, department) => new { 
        employee.Id, 
        employee.LastName, 
        DepartmentName = department.Name 
    }
);
```

if I have a class defined for the return type

```
public class EmployeeWithDept {
    public int Id {get;set}
    public string LastName {get;set}
    public string DepartmentName {get;set}
}
```

Can I explicitly write my `.Select()` to return `EmployeeWithDept`?

```
var query = db.From<Employee>()
    .Join<Department>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select<Employee, Department>((employee, department) => new EmployeeWithDept { 
        employee.Id, 
        employee.LastName, 
        DepartmentName = department.Name 
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#select-data-from-multiple-tables-into-a-custom-poco), yesno.
It is very much possible to get out your result POCO as long as you follow the naming conventions or decorated your types with the right attributes.

It should be as easy as:

```
var query = db.From<Employee>()
    .Join<Department>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Id);

var esWithDs = db.Select<EmployeeWithDept>(query);
```

Comment: unfortunately I'd still need the `query.Select()` because `EmployeeWithDept` has a property `DepartmentName` which isn't found on `Employee` or `Department`. It is `Department.Name`

Comment: Please have another more thorough look at the link to the docs I have provided. It is only 5 paragraphs. OrmLite supports exactly what you are referring to as long as you stick to the convention.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling `db.From<Employee>` the returned variable type is `SqlExpression<Employee>`.

So you can call it like this:

```
var query = db.From<Employee>()
    .Join<Department>()
    .OrderBy(e => e.Id)
    .Select<Employee, Department>((employee, department) => new { 
        Id = Sql.As(employee.Id, nameof(EmployeeWithDept.Id)), 
        LastName = Sql.As(employee.LastName, nameof(EmployeeWithDept.LastName)), 
        DepartmentName = Sql.As(department.Name, nameof(EmployeeWithDept.DepartmentName))
    }
);
var result = db.Select<EmployeeWithDept>(query);
```

This should work.